# Concatenating or combining ZIP files using SFTP

Tags: zip, concatenation, sftp

I am uploading files over 100MB and I am choosing to zip the files, split the .zip and then transferring the file parts. Once transferred to the SFTP, I do not see a command to combine the .zip parts. Does SFTP have such capability? I am using vsftp, which does not appear to have that functionality. I was wondering whether there is a universal SFTP command for the function.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's draft of [`copy-data`/`copy-file` extension to the SFTP protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-extensions-00), which can be used to concatenate files.

But in the most widespread OpenSSH SFTP server and OpenSSH SFTP client ([`sftp`](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp)) the `copy-data` is supported by very recent [version 9.0](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-9.0) only. Another servers that do support it are [ProFTPD `mod_sftp`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_sftp.html) and Bitvise SFTP server.

Comment: Hey there Martin, I did what I feel to be exhaustive research on the topic and see that you confirmed my findings. I'll be sure to check out Citvise SFTP server. Thanks!